# CORS issue while making AJAX to elasticsearch on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, cors

I have demo client in javascript that attempts to do a search on Elasticsearch that runs happily on Amazon AWS Cloud.

Thing is that I am getting the result back (fiddler shows it comes nicely in JSON, as it should be). But the browser is hitting me with this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9200/pekara/hljeb/_search. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:7000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

This is the demo Ajax that I use:

```
  var searchString = "http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9200/pekara/hljeb/_search";

        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: searchString,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("And this is success: " + data);

                $("#contentholder").text(data);
            }
        }).fail(function (error) {
            console.log("Search Failed")
        })
    }
```

So to repeat, Fiddler shows the result comes back, but browser points to fail method every single time.
How to resolve CORS in this example?

The demo application is being server on Node.js.

This is content of my elasticsearch.yaml file:

The rest  of the file is default, meaning everything is commented out:

```
    {
  "cluster.name": "Mycluster",
  "node.name": "My-node",
  "cloud": {
    "aws": {
      "access_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "secret_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  },
  "discovery": {
    "type": "ec2",
          "ec2" : {
        "groups": "Elastic-Search-GROUP"
   }
 }
}


http.cors.allow-origin: true,
http.cors.allow-methods: true,
http.cors.allow-headers: true,
http.cors.allow-credentials: true,
http.cors.enabled: true
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is implemented and applicable only to browsers and not apps (Fiddler/Rest Client et al)

Your server needs to allow the domains that are going to access the service via javascript. Configure your elastic search to do so. Update the [http config](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html) to do so. Relevant properties: `http.cors.enabled`, `http.cors.allow-origin`, `http.cors.allow-methods`, `http.cors.allow-headers`, `http.cors.allow-credentials`

If you want to do it via the vm parameters, use these while starting the process:

```
elasticsearch -Des.http.<property1>=<val1> -Des.http.<property2>=<val2> ...
```

**[EDIT]**

Extend your .json file by adding this:

```
"http": {
    "cors.enabled" : true,
    "cors.allow-origin": "*"
}
```

Comment: So I add these properties to elasticsearch.yaml file?

Comment: Yes, that would be better.

Comment: Trying it as we speak :). Will post the results ASAP

Comment: I have added those properties to elasticsearch.yaml and rebooted the server. Still same issues.

Comment: What do the properties look like? Can you show them?

Comment: I have added elasticsearch.yaml to my original question.

Comment: **But where are the values?** Also you need to set `http.cors.enabled` to `true`.

Comment: I am really confused with this yaml format. I coudl not get it to work with yaml, so I used JSON as a setting. What should I do now?

Comment: I have updated the configuration file again. Can you please take a look at it? :)

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Also, true is not applicable to all parameters. I would recommend you to read the `JSON` message format, `CORS` and `HTTP headers`. The configurations would make sense then.

Comment: Hold on. Right now, the `*` indicates that all origins are allowed to access your es services. However, you should protect it by limiting the domains. For that, specify only a set of domains in the [allow-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Well, only if you want to prevent them.

Comment: I struggled with the syntax of yaml and here is the another link i found with syntax https://pastebin.com/R5CjqwdG